# When is a subset of $\ell^2$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

I have been looking on the internet for hours now and even asking in chat without an answer. When is a set $M\subseteq\ell^2$ compact? For $L^p$, there is the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem that provides a useful tool, but I dont know how you can transfer it to $\ell^2$? Are there any similar theorems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the following characterization:

$S\subset \ell^2$ is compact if and only the following conditions are satisfies:

- $S$ is closed;
- $S$ is bounded, i.e. $\sup_{x\in S}\lVert x\rVert_{\ell^2}<\infty$;
- we have $\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sup_{x\in S}\sum_{k=N}^{+\infty}|x_k|^2=0$.

Comment: Of note: A generalization of this holds for $\ell_p$-spaces, $1\le p<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really surprised that this definition/characterization is nowhere to be found (I searched wikipedia and dozens of scripts)

Comment: @CBenni see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/175277/19538) the prooof of this characterization