# $A = \{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_ke_k :|a_k|\leq c_k \} \subset \mathcal H$ is compact, where $\sum c_k^2<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, compactness

The following is the exercise #24 in chapter 4 of Stein's Real Analysis.

> Let $\{e_k\}$ be an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. If $\{c_k\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum c_k^2<\infty$, then the set
> $$A = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_ke_k :|a_k|\leq c_k \right\}$$
> is compact in $H$.

I refered to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430287/sum-c-k2-infty-then-a-sum-k-1-infty-a-ke-k-a-k-leq-c-k-is-c) and below is my trial.

Let $S_0 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,...):a_k \in \mathbb C, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k e_k \in A \}$, $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n,k}e_k \in A$, and $A_1 = \{a_{n,1} \}_n$. $|a_{n,1}| \le c_1 \forall n$, so $A_1$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb C$. Then, there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_j,1} \}_j$ such that $\lim_{j\to \infty}a_{n_j,1} = b_1\quad (|b_1| \le |c_1|)$.

Let $S_1 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,...):a_1 \in A_1, S_1 \subset S_0 \}$, and $A_2 = \{a_{n,2} \}_n$....

Continuing this process inducively, $S_m$ can be obtained $(m \in \mathbb N)$ so that $S_{m+1} \subset S_m$ and $\lim_{j\to \infty}a_{n_j,k} = b_k \quad (|b_k| \le |c_k|), k = 1,...,m$. $\{a_{n_j,k}\}_j$ is a sequence of kth element of $S_m$.

Let $f_{n_j} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_j,k}e_k$, and $f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k e_k$.

Then, $\Vert f_{n_j} - f \Vert = \Vert \sum_k (a_{n_j,k}-b_k)e_k \Vert \le \sum_k \Vert (a_{n_j,k}-b_k)e_k \Vert = \sum_k |a_{n_j,k}-b_k|$

After then, I wanted to show that $\lim_{j\to\infty} \Vert f_{n_j} - f \Vert = 0$, but I found it difficult to show
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{n_j,k}-b_k| = 0$$

Any comments about my trial, whether my approach is correct or not, some errors if exists, how to finish this, or other better ideas, would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ can be described in a more convenient way as
$$A=\left \{\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_kc_ke_k\,:\,|x_k|\le 1\right \}$$
The rest of the proof is standard but, in my opinion, slightly more transparent due to the modified description of $A.$

Let $u_n:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^{(n)}c_ke_k$ be a sequence in $A.$
Then $\{x^{(n)}_k\}_{n=1}^\infty$ form a  family of sequences indexed by $k,$ all bounded by $1.$ By applying the diagonal method  we get a subsquence $n_j$ such that $x^{(n_j)}_k$ is convergent for every $k.$ WLOG we may assume that $x^{(n)}_k$ is convergent for every $k.$ Let $x_k=\lim_n x^{(n)}_k.$ Then $|x_k|\le 1.$  Fix $\varepsilon>0.$ There exists $K$ such that $\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty c_k^2<\varepsilon ^2.$
Hence
$$\left \|\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^{(n)}c_ke_k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_kc_ke_k\right \|\\ \le \sum_{k=1}^K |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|c_k+\left \|\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty x_k^{(n)}c_ke_k\right \|+\left \|\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty x_kc_ke_k\right \|\\ = \sum_{k=1}^K |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|c_k+\left (\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty |x_k^{(n)}|^2c_k^2\right )^{1/2}+\left (\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty |x_k|^2c_k^2\right)^{1/2}
\\
\le \sum_{k=1}^K |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|c_k+2\varepsilon$$
Now the first finite sum is less than $\varepsilon$ if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question about your solution. I guess you've intended to show $\Vert \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty} x_k^{(n)}c_k e_k \Vert < \epsilon$ as well as $\Vert \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty} x_k c_k e_k \Vert < \epsilon$, which seem to be related to $\sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty} c_k^2 < \epsilon^2$. If that's the case, could you explain this more in detail? I found it difficult to connect these facts.

Comment: what if for $k$ odd $x^n_k = cos(2 \pi k/ M_1)$ and for $k$ even $x^n_k = sin(2 \pi k/M_2)$ where $M_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $M_2 = 2$ ? Can u now pick $n_j$ such that $x_k^{n_j}$ is convergent for every $k$ according to ur method or proof ? Your final conclusion is still correct. Basically Can u pls eloborate on your diagonal argument on uniformly picking $n_j$ for all $k$ ? that seems to be the crux of the proof.

Comment: I think $K$ and $n_j$ are related then the proof works. Not sure if uniformly for all $k$, you can find an $n_j$.

Comment: @jason1 I have re-edited adding one line. The Parseval identity is used as the elements of the series are orthogonal.