# Hilbert space, orthonormal system, compact set of vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Could you help me solve this problem?

> Let $e_1, e_2, ...$ be an orthonormal system in a Hilbert space, $\delta_1, \delta_2 ... \in (0, + \infty)$. Prove that the set of all vectors $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \lambda_n e_n,  \ \ \lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}, \ \ |\lambda_n| \le \delta_n \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ is compact $\iff$ $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}\delta_n^2$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$C_{\mathbf{\delta}}:=\left\{\sum_{n}\lambda_ne_n, \left|\lambda_n\right|\leqslant \delta_n,\sum_{n}\lambda_n^2\lt\infty, \left|\lambda_n\right|\leqslant\delta_n\right\}.$$
If $C_{\delta}$ is compact, then the sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n\geqslant  1}      $ given by $x_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_je_j$ has a convergent subsequence, hence the sequence $\left(\lVert x_n\rVert^2\right )_{n\geqslant 1}     $ is bounded.

For the converse, use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379613/when-is-a-subset-of-ell2-compact?rq=1).

Comment: What does the symbol $(x_n)_n$ mean? Why use two subscripts $n$?

Comment: @JiaqiLi  I modified the notation.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's much clearer, thanks!