# Closed set in $l_{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I need to show that the set $A=\left\{ x \in l_{2} : |x_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}, n=1, 2, ...\right\}$ is a closed subset of $l_{2}$

I'm assuming the best way to show this is to have a sequence in A that converges to x, and show that this implies x is in A. But the manipulation is evading me.

Comment: If a sequence converges in $l^2,$ then it converges in each component.

Comment: Here's a related question with many others linked: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/175251/ (it gives a more general result, not a duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{ x^{(m)} = (x_1^{(m)}, x_2^{(m)},\ldots ) \}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $A$ and assume that $x^{(m)} \to x$ in $\ell^2$ as $m \to \infty$. To show that $A$ is closed, we need to show that $x \in A$. Write $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, then $x^{(m)} \to X$ in $\ell^2$ means that
$$
\| x^{(m)}-x \|_{\ell^2}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x^{(m)}_n - x_n |^2 \to 0 \textrm{ as $m \to \infty$.}
$$
In particular, for each fixed $n$, $|x_n^{(m)} - x_n | \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$. Therefore,
$$
|x_n| \leq |x_n^{(m)} - x_n | + |x_n^{(m)}| \leq |x_n^{(m)} - x_n| + \frac{1}{n},
$$
and taking the limit as $m \to \infty$ gives that $|x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Since this holds for all $n$, we may conclude that $x \in A$, and hence that $A$ is closed.

Comment: This is basically what I had, but in taking the limit we have, for a fixed $\epsilon$, $\exists m$ such that $|x^{(m)}_{n} - x_{n}| < \epsilon$. Which implies that for all $\epsilon$, $|x_{n}| < \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}$. How does this imply that $|x_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}?

Comment: Indeed, so what you would effectively have shown is that $|x_n| \leq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, hence $|x_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I'm not following that last implication

Comment: If $|x_n| > \frac{1}{n}$, then there has to be some $\epsilon > 0$ (take, e.g., $\epsilon = \frac{|x_n| - \frac{1}{n}}{2}$) so that $|x_n | > \epsilon + \frac{1}{n} $...

Answer (score 5):

Consider continuous functionals
$$
f_n:\ell_2\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x_n
$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that $A_n:=(f_n)^{-1}([-1/n,1/n])$ is closed as preimage of closed set under continuous map $f_n$. Since $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, then $A$ is closed as intersection of closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously 
$$
A=\left[-1,1\right]\times\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]\times\ldots\times\left[-\frac1n,\frac1n\right]\times\ldots=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[-\frac1n,\frac1n\right].
$$
Given $a\in \bar{A}$, there is a sequence $(a^k)$ of elements of $A$ whose limit is $a$, i.e. $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|a-a^k\|_2=0$. Therefore, for every $k,n\ge 1$ we have:
$$
|a_n|\le |a_n^k|+|a_n-a_n^k|\le \frac1n+\|a-a^k\|_2.
$$
It follows that
$$
|a_n|\le \frac1n+\lim_{k\to\infty}\|a-a^k\|_2=\frac1n \quad \forall n\ge 1,
$$
i.e. $a=(a_n)\in A$. Hence $\bar{A}\subset A\subset \bar{A}$, i.e. $A=\bar{A}$ and $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The complement of $A$ is 
$$
A^c=\left\{y\in l_2: |y_i|>\frac{1}{i}\text{ for some }i\right\}.
$$
If you are having trouble with your method, you could show that $A^c$ is open.