# Showing the "traditional" Hilbert Cube $C$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am looking for a way to prove that the Hilbert Cube is compact as a subset of $\ell^2$ using Tychonoff's Theorem. As I've found, this can be done using the fact that C is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is, by Tychonoff, compact when endowed with the metric $d(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{1}{2^j}|x_j-y_j|$.

It seems to me that one possible homeomorphism is $h: [-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow C$ defined by $h(x)=(x_1,\dfrac{x_2}{2},...,\dfrac{x_i}{i},...)$, but I'm not being able to prove its continuity, how can I do it?
I checked [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/how-to-show-that-this-set-is-compact-in-ell2) but I don't get the proof of the continuity of $F$ as it doesn't use the metric. I'm sure someone who knows general topology can easily translate it to metric-terms, I'd appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance!

PS: With "traditional" Hilbert Cube I mean $C=\{ \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}: 0\leq x_n \leq \dfrac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: Can you change the first metric to $d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j^2}|y_j-x_j|$?

Comment: @LutzL You mean the metric on $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$? I don't think so, cause that seems to me the core of the problem. But I guess that if I can justify that change, surely I could.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $x_n \to x$ in $[-1,1]^{\mathbb N},$ then $x_n(k) \to x(k)$ for each $k.$

Comment: Thanks! Is it an equivalence in this particular case, isn't it? If so, I think I got it, but I'm not very sure how to prove it is indeed an equivalence, as I think that's not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

One way to homeomorpically embed $C$ into Hilbert space is to let $F((x_i)_i)=((2^{-i}x_i)_i).$ Then $\|F(x)-F(y)\|\leq d(x,y)$ so $F$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: That's pretty concise and cristal clear, thanks! I'm not sure, though, how to show that $F$ thus defined is surjective, it seems intuitively so but I can't work out the details.

Comment: Surjective to what? If $D=\{f(x): x\in C\}$ then $f:C\to D$ then $f$ is a continuous bijection from one compact Hausdorff space to another so $  f:C\to D$ is a homeomorphism. ($D$ is compact because it's the continuous image of $C.$)

Comment: Yeah! I mean the fact that $F([-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}})=C$.

Comment: I was using $C$ to mean $ [-1,1]^{\mathbb N} ,$ not the "traditional"$C,4 and mapping it to a subset of Hilbert space.

Comment: Oh, got it. But then I honestly don't see how that solves my problem, does it?